# can't print my result on "ride.out" file

Tags: java

I'm having trouble with the first problem on the USACO Training Page.

The task is asking for two strings from a `ride.in` file, converting the strings into a number that is the product of the letters (where a=1, b=2, z=26), then seeing if the remainders of the numbers = 47 (if they are, print "GO", if not, print "STAY" on `ride.out`).

I don't know why I can't print my output on `ride.out`.

The code I wrote is:

```
package ashish.usaco.com;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.*;

class ride {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("ride.in"));
            // input file name goes above
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("ride.out")));

            // Use StringTokenizer vs. readLine/split -- lots faster
            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(input.readLine());

            if (toNumber(st.nextToken()) % 47 == toNumber(st.nextToken()) % 47) {
                out.println("GO");
            } else {
                out.println("STAY");
            }
            out.close();
            input.close();
            System.exit(0);
        } catch(NoSuchElementException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found");
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("File not Found"); 
        }
    }

    public static  int toNumber (String name) {

        int pdtvalue =1, charvalue =1;

        for(int i=0; i<name.length();i++)
        {
            charvalue = (name.charAt(i) - 'A')+1;
            pdtvalue*= charvalue;
        }
        return pdtvalue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get some exception, or is the output file just not created? Perhaps you are looking for it in the wrong location.

Comment: output file has been created. i got the "file not found " from the "NoSuchElementException" block.

Comment: Note that, among other "best practices", your `package` really should be the other way around: `com.usaco.ashish`.  Packages are usually named going from most-general to most-specific.

Comment: You have two exceptions that print the same text. You should change the text of one of them so you can see which is being thrown.  You should also print `e.getMessage()` to see *why* the exception was thrown.

Comment: e.getMessage() is giving me null

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone for their help..

thanks specially alobodkz.. you really told the right part. My ride.java program could not find the ride.in file because it was not in the correct directory.. i deleted the entire package containing the code and wrote a fresh ride.java class file and this time without the
package statement   ..

Answer (score 0):

In this statement:

`if (toNumber(st.nextToken()) % 47 == toNumber(st.nextToken()) % 47)`

You are not checking if reminders of a number equal 47.
You are checking if reminders of both numbers % (modulo operator) 47 are equal to each other.

So if for instance first token == 47 and the second token == 94 -> your condition is true, so it's completely different logic from what you presented in your problem description.

Comment: you mean i should try like this: if ((toNumber(st.nextToken()) % 47 == 0) && (toNumber(st.nextToken()) % 47 == 0))

Comment: That depends on your requirements. You can have reminders after using all operators, not only modulo: 50 - 3 = 47. So it's important what operation are you suppose to use and what are operands of this operation. From what you said for instance I would guess that maybe it's something like: firstToken % secondToken == 47?

Comment: Because the problem is somewhere else. You have problem with the fact, that your program doesn't find a ride.in file. Put this System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir")); in the beginning of your code and copy your file into directory that it shows you.